# Page refresh before the express - Node js function ends

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have the following function that works with small files that can be uploaded in few seconds but with big files the page refresh without the axios post request on express js ends. I am working with React Js . SO below is the client server react js that makes the axios request to port 9000 in the same domain

```
 function handleUpload (event)  {
    event.preventDefault();
    var language=props.selectedlan.selectedlan;
    var data = language === LAN_EN?jsonEN.deliverablePage:jsonGR.deliverablePage;
    
    if (projectName==='' || selectPerc === null) {
      setMessage(data.page.value16);
      return;
    }
    else if (!(selectPerc <=100 && selectPerc >=0)) {
      setMessage(data.page.value17);
      return;
    }
    else if (maxGrade < 0 ) {
      setMessage(data.page.value18);
      return;
    }
    setMessage('' );
    const dataFile = new FormData();
    dataFile.append('file', selectedFile);
    dataFile.append('id', props.loginsession.ID);
    dataFile.append('name', projectName);
    dataFile.append('startDate', selectedSDate);
    dataFile.append('finishDate', selectedFDate);
    dataFile.append('percentage', selectPerc);
    dataFile.append('max', maxGrade);
    dataFile.append('appear', checkedB);
    axios
      .post('http://10.16.33.114:9000/createDeliverable', dataFile, {
        onUploadProgress: (ProgressEvent) => {
          setloaded(Math.round(
            (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total) * 100
          ));
        }
      }).then(    setselectedFile(null))
      .then(
        setMessage(data.page.value19))
.then(setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace('/app/deliverables?createDeliverable=1'); }, 2000));
  };
```

Below we can see the Server side from express js that is call the axios post:

```
  fs.readdir(`${process.cwd()}/public/uploads/DeliverablesDocumentInfo/`, (err, files) => {
      con.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
        //Select all customers and return the result object:
        if(req.body.file !== 'null' ){

          let uploadFile = req.files.file;
          const name = uploadFile.name;
        
          con.query('INSERT INTO deliverables (Title,StartDate,FinishDate,Percentage, MaxGrade,Appear) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',[projectName,start, finish,percentage, max,appear], async function (err, result, fields) {
            connection.release();
  
            if (err) throw err;
          
            var insertedID = result.insertId;
            let ex = name.split(".")[1];
            const saveAs = insertedID+"." + ex;
          
            uploadFile.mv(`${process.cwd()}/public/uploads/DeliverablesDocumentInfo/${saveAs}`, function(err) {
             if (err) {
              // return res.status(500).send(err);
             }
             });
             con.query("UPDATE deliverables SET FileData = ? WHERE IDDeliverable = ?",[saveAs,insertedID], function (err, result) {
               if (err) throw err;
             });
        });
        }
        else{

            con.query('INSERT INTO deliverables (Title,StartDate,FinishDate,Percentage, MaxGrade,Appear) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)',[projectName,start, finish,percentage, max,appear], async function (err, result, fields) {
                connection.release();
                if (err) throw err;      
            });
            }
      res.status(200);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass functions to `then`. Your code is creating a 2 seconds timeout at the moment the `post` starts, not when it finishes.

Corrected version:

```js
function handleUpload (event)  {
    event.preventDefault();
    var language=props.selectedlan.selectedlan;
    var data = language === LAN_EN?jsonEN.deliverablePage:jsonGR.deliverablePage;
    
    if (projectName==='' || selectPerc === null) {
      setMessage(data.page.value16);
      return;
    }
    else if (!(selectPerc <=100 && selectPerc >=0)) {
      setMessage(data.page.value17);
      return;
    }
    else if (maxGrade < 0 ) {
      setMessage(data.page.value18);
      return;
    }
    setMessage('' );
    const dataFile = new FormData();
    dataFile.append('file', selectedFile);
    dataFile.append('id', props.loginsession.ID);
    dataFile.append('name', projectName);
    dataFile.append('startDate', selectedSDate);
    dataFile.append('finishDate', selectedFDate);
    dataFile.append('percentage', selectPerc);
    dataFile.append('max', maxGrade);
    dataFile.append('appear', checkedB);
    axios
      .post('http://10.16.33.114:9000/createDeliverable', dataFile, {
        onUploadProgress: (ProgressEvent) => {
          setloaded(Math.round(
            (ProgressEvent.loaded / ProgressEvent.total) * 100
          ));
        }
      })
      .then(() => setselectedFile(null))
      .then(() => setMessage(data.page.value19))
      .then(() => setTimeout(function(){ window.location.replace('/app/deliverables?createDeliverable=1'); }, 2000));
  };
```

Comment: I try it. It successfully upload the file but the page is not refresh. It is like no one 'then' it is compiled

Comment: It looks like you should first see if there is an error in the promise chain. You can try to add a `.catch` at the end to make sure `setselectedFile` and `setMessage` work properly.

Comment: If a refresh the page manually I can se the uploaded file and the the record created. But when I click the button to upload it stacks on 100% but no refresh and no message appears (no one of the 3 ()=> .. it executes )

Comment: Then my next guess is that the server doesn't properly end the request. It's hard to know what's going on from just a bit of the client code. Maybe post the handler on the server side.

Comment: I add the client server too

Comment: Not 100% sure, but maybe you need to end the request: `res.send('OK'); // HTTP 200 by default`. I think that as is your server is never sending a response.